# Convert a mysql query intro a json object

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my code :

```
$eventList = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($produse)){

$url   = $http_location . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $rows['title']) . '.html' ;   
$image = ($rows['image_path'][0] == "." ? $http_location.substr($rows['image_path'], 1) : $r['image_path']);

$eventList[] = array(
    //'id' => $rows['productid'],
    'Title' => $rows['productname'],
    'Description' => $rows['description'],
    'Short message' => '',
    'Price' => $rows['price'],
    'Category' => $rows['category'],
    'Subcategory' => '',
    'URL' => $url,
    'Image' => $image,
    'Product ID' => $rows['productid'],
    'Generate link text' => 0,
    'Brand' => $rows['manufacturer'],
    'Active' => 1,
    'Other data' => ''
);

unset($url, $image);
}


// print '<pre>';
// print_r($eventList);

//header('Content-Type: application/json');

$eventList = json_encode($eventList);

echo json_encode($eventList);

mysql_close();
```

And this is the result of query :

> "[{\"Title\":\"Costum buburuza\",\"Description\":\"Costum buburuza copii pentru fete, include rochia cu bretele din lycra, cu aplicatie floare, fuste din satin imprimat si tull pe interior, maneci detasabile, aripi si cordeluta cu antenute.\",\"Short message\":\"\",\"Price\":\"119.00\",\"Category\":\"Costume Carnaval\",\"Subcategory\":\"\",\"URL\":\"http:\/\/www.fabricademagie.ro\/Costum-buburuza-copii-fete.html\",\"Image\":\"http:\/\/www.fabricademagie.ro\/images\/P\/63442-01.jpg\",\"Product ID\":\"5\",\"Generate link text\":0,\"Brand\":null,\"Active\":1,\"Other data\":\"\"},{\"Title\":\"Costum buburuza\",\"Description\":\"Costum buburuza copii pentru fete, include rochia cu bretele din lycra, cu aplicatie floare, fuste din satin imprimat si tull pe interior, maneci detasabile, aripi si cordeluta cu antenute.\",\"Short message\":\"\",\"Price\":\"114.00\",\"Category\":\"Costume Carnaval\",\"Subcategory\":\"\",\"URL\":\"http:\/\/www.fabricademagie.ro\/Costum-buburuza-copii-fete.html\",\"Image\":\"http:\/\/www.fabricademagie.ro\/images\/P\/63442-01.jpg\",\"Product ID\":\"5\",\"Generate link text\":0,\"Brand\":null,\"Active\":1,\"Other data\":\"\"}]"

What I am doing wrong and I recive this type of result instead of a standar json object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second json_encode() function from your code. It should look like this:

```
$eventList = json_encode($eventList);
echo $eventList;
```

Or, as mentioned above already:

```
echo json_encode($eventList);
```

It would also be wise to look into replacing all mysql() functions into mysqli or PDO, or a library that makes use of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
$eventList = json_encode($eventList);
echo json_encode($eventList);
```

You twice encode string....

```
$eventList = json_encode($eventList);
echo $eventList;
```

TADA ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove one of your json_encode :

```
$eventList = json_encode($eventList);

echo $eventList;
```

or

```
echo json_encode($eventList);
```